# Как сделать запрос с явными преобразованиями типов данных?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть запрос, но мне сказали сделать его с явными преобразованиями типом данных.

Подскажите, как сделать и куда смотреть в этом случае?

```
select
  CMS.ARTICLE, CMS.name 
from  supermag.smcard cms 
left join (
  SELECT  ost.ARTICLE, sum (OST.QUANTITY) quanto 
  from supermag.SMGOODS ost 
  GROUP BY ost.ARTICLE) ost on (ost.ARTICLE=CMS.ARTICLE and OST.QUANTO=0) 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT logi.article 
    FROM supermag.SMCARDSECURITYLOG logi 
    where logi.ACTIONCODE = 1 
    and logi.EVENTTIME between (RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate))-90 
    and RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)) n on (n.article=cms.article) 
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT reps.article 
      from supermag.FFMAPREP reps  
      where reps.saletype NOT IN ('WI', 'WO', 'IW', 'CS', 'CR', 'PO', 'PN', 'PE') 
      and REPS.SALEDATE between RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sFirstDate) 
      and RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)) reps on (reps.ARTICLE=CMS.ARTICLE) 
where CMS.ARTICLE=OST.ARTICLE 
and OST.QUANTO is not null 
and cms.ACCEPTED=1  
and n.article is null
and reps.article is null
GROUP BY CMS.ARTICLE, cms.Name
```

Comment: @Akina Подскажите пожалуйста, где вы увидели Java код?

Comment: @Akina То был не Java код. Кусочки из приложения остались при переносе, ну с кем не случается.

Comment: **@Уважаемые коллеги**, не стоит минусовать и закрывать из-за ошибки при копи-пасте кода. В целом вопрос, несмотря на огрехи оформления, нормальный.

Comment: @0xdb Код смотрелся вполне цельным. У меня ХШ в ремонте, так что увидеть, что это огрех копипаста, было несколько проблемно. PS. Минус - не мой. Вот голос за закрытие - мой, ибо я не вижу способа распознать, где тут требуется сделать явным преобразование типа (у меня ХШ ...).

Comment: PPS. `RepSqlText.ToSqlDate(sLastDate)` - это точно SQL-код? https://docs.oracle.com/search/?q=RepSqlText доблестно рапортует "Я фиг знает что это такое".

Comment: @Akina _это точно SQL-код?_, это может быть SQL-код: `package_name.func_name`, или тоже функция из приложения, забытая после удаления кавычек и конкантенаци. В контексте вопроса роли не играет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> но мне сказали сделать его с явным типом преобразований

Те, кто это сказал, имели ввиду следующее.

Во первых, ознакомится и понять разницу между [явным и неявным преобразованием](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-4C49C87F-F170-43CC-9EDC-2403576610DF) типов данных. В этой гл. в первых строчках перечисленно, почему предпочтительно использовать явные преобразования.

> Oracle **recommends that you specify explicit conversions**, rather than rely on implicit or automatic conversions [...]

Например, в следующем запросе все преобразования неявные и он рабочий:

```
create table tab (numcol int, chrcol varchar2 (8), datcol date)
/
create or replace function foo (val varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin return val;
end;
/
select numcol, chrcol, datcol--to_char (datcol, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
from tab
where numcol = '123'
and chrcol = foo (567) 
and trunc (datcol) = '29.04.2021'
/
no rows selected
```

Но при изменении настроек/параметров сессии или БД, запрос выше, в лучшем случае, выдаст ошибку, а в худшем, даст неверный результат, который нарушит логику приложения его вызвавшего.

В следующем примере этого не случится:

```
select numcol, chrcol, to_char (datcol, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') datcol
from tab
where numcol = to_number ('123', 'fm99999999')
and chrcol = foo (to_char (567, 'fm99999999')) 
and trunc (datcol) = to_date ('29.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
/
no rows selected
```

Аналогично примерам выше, найдите все неявные преобразования в запросе из вопроса, замените их явными, и задача будет успешно решена.